# Generate all combinations of array of arrays

Tags: c#, sequence, permutation

I am unsing c#..

I have an araay of arrays, can grow to 30.

```
char[][] myArray = new char[][]{
 
        new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' },
    new char[] { '3', '2', '1' }
};
```

Want to create all combinations in format

"3333333333333333
3333333333333332
3333333333333331
3333333333333323
3333333333333322
3333333333333321
3333333333333313
3333333333333312
3333333333333311
3333333333333233
3333333333333232
..........."

I applied two approaches, First:

```
var data=myArray.Aggregate((IEnumerable<string>)new[] { string.Empty }, (e, d) => e.SelectMany(_ => d, (a, b) => a + b)).ToList();
File.AppendAllText(@$"C:\test.txt", (String.Join(Environment.NewLine,data)));
```

In this appraoch, can generate sequences pretty quick as long as array count is 16. Above 16, I run into memory issue.

Second approach is

```
var positions = from list1 in mainList
                from list2 in mainList
                from list3 in mainList
                from list4 in mainList
......
 select new
 {
     list1,
     list2,
     list3,
....
```

Then use Parallel for loop using 32 threads.
In second appraich, after running over 24 hours the loop is still running.

Is there another way to to do this faster wihtout running into memory issues...

Comment: You want all permutations of 3 chars to a string length of 30? Why do you need the initial array in the first place? Is the actual problem different?

Comment: I can remove that, it is not necessary to have an initial array

Comment: Then just create loops and in the most inner loop write directly to the file. Don't try to maintain what you have created in memory. Directly write it to a file and then forget about that data. There are gazillions of examples on how todo that on the internet. Pick one you like. One i [like](https://code-maze.com/csharp-generate-permutations/)

Comment: There are examples out there, but at some point computer resources are the limit. With recursion, it can be done, but looking for what is the most time efficient way to do this

Comment: Time and Memory Efficiency are typically mutually exclusive. You have to decide whats more relevant here. You can't have both. I would suggest some Divide&Conquer approach. Pre-divide the result set for example by the first two character then append the rest in there own loops to complete the permutation. Do that in their own threads into their own files and then merge the files afterwards.

Comment: There are 3^30 = `205.891.132.094.649` values by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have 1, 2 and 3 as possible values. So they very much look like digits of a number. Let's create an initial array to have the state stored somewhere:

```
char[] myArray = new char[]{
 
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
};
```

and let's create an array of values:

```
char[] values = new char[] {'1', '2', '3'};
```

Now, let's do a loop:

```
bool ended = false;
while (!ended) {
    bool done = false;
    int index = myArray.Length - 1;
    while ((!done) && (index >= 0)) {
        int valueIndex = values.IndexOf(myArray[index]);
        valueIndex = (valueIndex + 1) % values.Length;
        if ((valueIndex == 0) && (index == 0)) {
            ended = true;
            done = true;
        } else {
            myArray[index] = values[valueIndex];
            if (valueIndex == 0) {
                index--;
            } else {
                done = true;
                //output current state in the way you like
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We are basically "incrementing" a 3-base number where the array elements represent the digits.

EDIT

Concerns were expressed regarding `IndexOf` in the comment section. This is an implementation without `IndexOf`:

```
bool ended = false;
while (!ended) {
    bool done = false;
    int index = myArray.Length - 1;
    while ((!done) && (index >= 0)) {
        int valueIndex = myArray[index];
        valueIndex = (valueIndex + 1) % values.Length;
        if ((valueIndex == 0) && (index == 0)) {
            ended = true;
            done = true;
        } else {
            if (valueIndex == 0) {
                index--;
            } else {
                done = true;
                //output current state in the way you like
                //keep in mind that we will need to print
                //values[myArray[someindex]] in this scenario
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, if we choose this approach, we will need to store the indexes in `myArray` rather than the actual values to be able to compute things based on them without `IndexOf` and hence we need to keep this in mind when we display the values too.

Comment: That `IndexOf` for `values` smells pretty heavy.

Comment: @AKX can you elaborate? (not an active C# dev for quite a while)

Comment: I mean, it looks like an additional O(n) loop over `values`, whereas iterating over all base-3 numbers with a given keyspace per character in the output string should not involve that.

Comment: @AKX the number of possible digit-values usually is not that much. Sure, if you work in base-1000 or something, then this may become an issue, but if not, then the number of digits in your number are what contribute more to complexity really. Nevertheless, I'll make an edit to get rid of `IndexOf` for the case when the number of possible values for a digit is a concern.

Comment: @AKX added an implementation without using `IndexOf` for the case when the number-base is potentially big-enough to concern us.

Comment: If all of the (up-to-30) arrays are of the same length, doesn't this problem basically just boil down to formatting integers 0..N**30 in `base-N` using the characters from the up-to-30 arrays per digit position?

Comment: Using a loop is not that efficient, again ran parallel for loop, it ran over 24 hrs but still not complete.

Comment: @AKX we speak about digits of a base-N number, yes. Here our digits are 0, 1, 2, displayed as '1', '2', '3'. But why should we have many arrays for the values, when it's enough to know the possible digits exactly once and store the state of the number as an array of the current digit values?

Comment: OP isn't saying they'll always have `3`/`2`/`1` (not `1`/`2`/`3`!), but what if they'd want `[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ...]` i.e. different "digits" per digit position?

Comment: @teste first, I'm pretty sure you are not speaking about the loop I have shared here, given the fact that at the time of this writing my answer is 1-hour-old and you speak about waiting for 24 hours. So your observation may be about loops, but not about the loop in this answer. Second, I wonder what algorithm could you invent that would be more efficient. So, please at least test this loop before dismissing it. And test first with smaller arrays to find the more efficient algorithm without waiting for too much.

Comment: @AKX that can also be achieved, but in the question we had the same possible digit values for each digit. But, if there were different digit types and counts, then a mapping would be needed and some understanding of which digit corresponds to what value set.

Comment: The _example_ in OP's post happens to use the same digits per position, but I don't see a reason to limit ourselves to that, since it's really just a matter of how to format an integer in base-N. As for the duration: since this problem really is just looping over all integers from 0 to N**M and formatting them, it's [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel): just slice the range of integers for multiple workers and let them do the work.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad no sir not at all, I am not dismissing your solution out right, I am talking about similar loop scenario, either using nest for loop, parallel for, etc.  The main issue on this problem is, the number of permutation, it's a factorial of 30 multiplied with 3.  This bloats the number of iteration code has to go though to generate this text. (30 factorial = 265252859812191058636308480000000 (took from google)) multiply this numer by 3.

Comment: @teste the loop you have tested with may be different from the one suggested here. So we have two options: either you share your loop as an edit to the question and we look into that, or you test the one I have suggested. Complexity is problematic indeed, welcome to the world of complexity, you will get used to algorithms not finishing very quickly if they are complex. The question is whether we can improve the complexity in this case. And you are being a bit naive. This is not the number of permutation. This is Descartes-multiplication.

Comment: @teste when you have n unique elements and you need to find all the possible order of these elements, then you have premutations. But when you have n non-unique elements and you need to combine all possible values for all elements with all possible values of the other elements, then you get unfiltered Descartes-multiplication, which is way more complex than permutation. See more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Comment: @teste there is no doubt that as the number of items grows the algorithm becomes increasingly slow to proceed. This will be true for any algorithm. But the question is: how we can improve upon the algorithm. Yes, you can parallelize it with workers/threads, but first you need to have solid understanding of the algorithm you are about to parallelize. The algorithm I proposed treats the items as digits and increments them.

Comment: @teste doing work exactly as if you were counting in base-10. If you have a lot to count, it will take time. No way around that. All you can do is to try to count more efficiently. If you can pass on the counting to 10 employees, then you will ask first to count the numbers of a certain digit count starting with 1, the second will do it with the numbers starting with 2, and so on, the last counting the numbers "starting with 0" (that is, the numbers having less digits). So it can be made parallel, but the workers will end up counting subsections too.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I ended up using this methodology. Using Aggregate code I postd, I created first file with iterations of 16 arrays, and second file with the rest. After that I merged the files, by concatenating each line from both files, one line at a time.

Comment: @teste happy to help. If this answer contributed to a solution or better understanding, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, this will do pretty much the same thing (conceptually):

```
char[][] myArray = new char[][]{
    new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' },
    new char[] { 'd', 'e', 'f' },
    new char[] { 'g', 'h', 'i' },
    new char[] { 'j', 'k', 'l' },
};
var digits = myArray.Length;
var numBase = myArray[0].Length;

for (int number = 0; number < Math.Pow(numBase, digits); number++)
{
    var str = new char[digits];
    var nNumber = number;
    for(int j = 0; j < digits; j++) {
        str[j] = myArray[j][nNumber % numBase];
        nNumber /= numBase;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this could be an [XY](https://xyproblem.info/) problem. And you don't actually "need" an array of arrays, but this is your idea how to solve your mysterious original problem. I simply added an assumption that you will only iterate over this array of arrays. If that's true than C# has a great feature called `enumerators`.

This is a very short code that during compilation will be expanded into a dedicated class that implements `IEnumerator` interface. During enumeration it will `yield return` array of chars one by one without actually allocating the memory for the entire array.

```cs
IEnumerable<char[]> GenerateArrays(string digits, int length)
{
    var characters = new char[length];

    var combinations = Math.Pow(digits.Length, length);

    for (var i = 0L; i < combinations; i++)
    {
        var temp = i;

        for (var j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            characters[length - 1 - j] = digits[(int)(temp % digits.Length)];
            temp /= digits.Length;
        }

        yield return characters;
    }
}


foreach (var array in GenerateArrays("321", 30))
{
    Console.WriteLine(array);
}
```

executing that code returns:

```
(...)
333333333333333333133223121221
333333333333333333133223121213
333333333333333333133223121212
333333333333333333133223121211
333333333333333333133223121133
333333333333333333133223121132
333333333333333333133223121131
333333333333333333133223121123
333333333333333333133223121122
333333333333333333133223121121
333333333333333333133223121113
333333333333333333133223121112
333333333333333333133223121111
(...)
```

Comment: Again, have used enumerators, loops etc. my question is how can you do it without foreach loop... This is where it take the time

Comment: Like I said, you didn't explain very well what do you need the array for. You will have a hard time storing almost 206TB array in the RAM. The plus of this approach is that the values are generated at the same time you are using them.